# Older English Term

Tags: meaning, word-usage, british-english, orthography

My question is about a word I heard the other day in an audio book.  Phonetically, it sounded like "SAW-sir-us" and had to do with a soft souind of the wind, or a soft wooshing sound.  I believe it's an older term describing a stillness of all but the wind, before an event.  Has anyone the correct spelling and meaning?

Answer (score 1):

## *Susurrus*

There is a Latin word *susurrus* that meant a humming, muttering, or whispering. It was imported into English unchanged in the early 19th century, and [per the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/195244) has come to mean:

> A low soft sound as of whispering or muttering; a whisper; a rustling.

I myself tend to think of it as a light whispering wind.

It’s stressed on the middle syllable — in theory. It’s not a word you hear very often and people aren’t always sure how to say unfamiliar words. I may have heard it stressed on the first syllable before, as you have yourself indicated. It would have been on the middle syllable in Latin due to the double-consonant at the end, and that’s how the OED gives it. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/susurrus) gives both possibilities, although that’s crowd-sourced so anybody can write anything there.

Comment: The reader of the audio book may not have had the correct pronunciation.  It was a Terry Pratchett book; he loves to pepper his writings with obsolete terms and they're just lovely!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm Spanish speaker, and we use susurro exactly in that way! It is a nice word

Comment: @santimirandarp This is exactly why I immediately knew the word myself! ;)